# Iterating Through Collections in BackboneJs, is for faster than forEach?

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

> Iterating Through Collections: Although you can use a simple for loop
>   to iterate through your collection as follows:

```
//a simple loop
for(var i = 0; i < myLibrary.length; i++){
var model = myLibrary.at(i);
console.log('Book ' + i + ' is called ' + model.get('name'));
}
```

> there is a more elegant utility function provided by Underscore that
>   helps iterate through collections, namely, the forEach function.

```
//using forEach
myLibrary.forEach(function(model){
console.log('Book is called ' + model.get('name'));
});
```

Which one is better performance-wise

Comment: see: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-underscore-each-vs-for-loops/4

Comment: thanks! post this as answer I will select it as best

Comment: Fyi If it's about performance, I believe that it's good practice to cache the array length by default. Like this: `(i = 0, max = myarray.length; i < max; i++`.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [underscore source](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-15) you can see that it tests for the native forEach and then chooses that over using a for loop. So given your 2 options, on browsers that support the native forEach, Underscore will be much faster, and will have almost the same run time in all others.

```
var each = _.each = _.forEach = function(obj, iterator, context) {
    if (obj == null) return obj;
    if (nativeForEach && obj.forEach === nativeForEach) {
      obj.forEach(iterator, context);
    } else if (obj.length === +obj.length) {
      for (var i = 0, length = obj.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (iterator.call(context, obj[i], i, obj) === breaker) return;
      }
    } else {
      var keys = _.keys(obj);
      for (var i = 0, length = keys.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (iterator.call(context, obj[keys[i]], keys[i], obj) === breaker) return;
      }
    }
    return obj;
  };
```